# Subsites data not retrieved via the SOAP API

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, web-services

I have a vanilla setup of Sharepoint 2007.  A few subsites are also created.  When the SOAP API is used to access the base Sharepoint site (for eg. http://spserver.com) the list of subsites and other lists can be retrieved.

When we try to retrieve the data for a subsite using the subsite URL (for eg. http://spserver.com/site1) the webservice returns the data for the main site instead of the subsite.

This is happening when the site is accessed from multiple applications using the SOAP API so the issue is probably a configuration issue on the server.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved.  Sharepoint was setup without the FQDN and although the Web application was working, the REST API was not working and was always retrieving data for the root site.

Using the Central Administrator after the URL was changed to use the FQDN all is fine now and data is retrieved correctly.

Comment: Please mark as answer to help others to understand that the solution is found. Thank you.